# JQuery Click Event Not Firing on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a JQuery click event that doesn't seems to be firing at all. If I am missing something I'm almost certain it's something trivial. I've tried debugging the code via Chrome but the button click on the Filter button is not even hitting the breakpoint.

```
$('#filter').click(function () {
    var dataurl;
    var visit = $('#visitFilter').val;
    var dns = $('#dnsFilter').val;
    var visitdate = $('#visitDateFilter').val;
    var entrypage = $('#entryPageFilter').val;
    var timeOnSite = $('#timeOnSiteFilter').val;
    var timeonsiteselector = $('#timeOnSiteSelector').val;
    var pages = $('#pagesFilter').val;
    var cost = $('#costFilter').val;
    var city = $('#cityFilter').val;
    var country = $('#countryFilter').val;
    var keywords = $('#keywordsFilter').val;
    var referrer = $('#referrerFilter').val;

    dataurl = "http://localhost:56971/VisitListFilter/28/" + visit + "/" + dns + "/" + visitdate + "/" + entrypage + "/" + timeOnSite + "/" + timeonsiteselector + "/" + pages + "/" + cost + "/" + city + "/" + country + "/" + keywords + "/" + referrer + "/" + "?format=json";

    $('#VisitListTable').bootstrapTable('refresh', {url: dataurl});
});
```

I've also created a fiddle here with the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/W3R3W0LF666/epu54yc4/1/

Comment: There is nothing with id set to "filter" in your html code (provided in the fiddle), so the click event will not register

Comment: Is your table generating any dynamic html?

Comment: After seeing your code I smell something bad

Comment: There's this HTML element in the code on the fiddle: <input type="button" id="filter" class="btn btn-info" value="Filter Visitors" />

Comment: #filter is there. Please do check

Comment: @LianeStevenson right my bad sry. I see the button now. For some strange reason Ctrl+F could not find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember `.val()` is a function.

You need to use `()` when invoking a function. Currently you are just passing the function reference.

```
var visit = $('#visitFilter').val(); //Note ()
```

Comment: Thanks I've replaced that but still not working - works when I refresh the page though (as in works like a page load)

Answer (score 2):

It is getting fired.

> Blockquote[image]

Answer (score 2):

Replace all **.val** with **.val()** as .val() is a jquery function for getting values.as :

```
var dns = $('#dnsFilter').val;
```